# Show the next day of the week in golang

Tags: go, dayofweek

I've just started my study IT and I thought it would be fun to make a little program that would show you what day it is tomorrow. Sadly I'm stuck. Currently it's working when you write the correct number from the array, but I would like it to work with a string. So when you write 'Maandag' (monday in Dutch), the program will answer Dinsdag (Tuesday in Dutch)

This is my code so far:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var counter int

    var dag [7]string
    dag[0] = "Zondag"
    dag[1] = "Maandag"
    dag[2] = "Dinsdag"
    dag[3] = "Woensdag"
    dag[4] = "Donderdag"
    dag[5] = "Vrijdag"
    dag[6] = "Zaterdag"

    fmt.Println("Welke dag is het?")
    fmt.Scan(&counter)

    if counter == 6 {
        counter = 0
        fmt.Println(dag[counter])
    }

    if counter != 6 {
        counter++
        fmt.Println(dag[counter])
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a map instead of an array (https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/19), or a switch/case statement (https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you looking for are enums. In Go they can be implemented like this:

```
type Weekday int 

const (
   Sunday    Weekday = iota
   Monday    
   Tuesday   
   Wednesday 
   Thursday  
   Friday    
   Saturday   
)

func (day Weekday) String() string {
    // declare an array of strings
    // ... operator counts how many
    // items in the array (7)
    names := [...]string{
        "Sunday", 
        "Monday", 
        "Tuesday", 
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", 
        "Friday", 
        "Saturday"}
    // → `day`: It's one of the
    // values of Weekday constants.    
    // If the constant is Sunday,
    // then day is 0.
    // prevent panicking in case of
    // `day` is out of range of Weekday
    if day < Sunday || day > Saturday {
      return "Unknown"
    }
    // return the name of a Weekday
    // constant from the names array 
    // above.
    return names[day]
}

// will display "Sunday"
fmt.Println(Sunday)

// will display "Monday"
fmt.Println(Sunday + 1)
```

If you do not need int underlying type, you can create it like this:

```
const (
    Sunday = "Sunday"
     //...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Range over the array of days to get the value of its index. Check for the string passed and fetch the value of matched string index. Then use that index to get the value of next day:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var (
    counter int
    day     string
)

func main() {

    var dag [7]string
    dag[0] = "Zondag"
    dag[1] = "Maandag"
    dag[2] = "Dinsdag"
    dag[3] = "Woensdag"
    dag[4] = "Donderdag"
    dag[5] = "Vrijdag"
    dag[6] = "Zaterdag"

    fmt.Println("Welke dag is het?")
    fmt.Scan(&day)
    for key, value := range dag {
        if day == value {
            counter = key
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(counter)
    if counter == 6 {
        counter = 0
        fmt.Println(dag[counter])
    }

    if counter != 6 {
        counter = counter + 1
        fmt.Println(dag[counter])
    }
}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/pwFiWxav72Z)

Or as Peter suggested you can use maps also which is more convenient and easy to use in this case:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var value string
    dag := make(map[string]string)
    dag["Zondag"] = "Maandag"
    dag["Maandag"] = "Dinsdag"
    dag["Dinsdag"] = "Woensdag"
    dag["Woensdag"] = "Donderdag"
    dag["Donderdag"] = "Vrijdag"
    dag["Vrijdag"] = "Zaterdag"

    fmt.Println("Welke dag is het?")
    fmt.Scan(&value)
    fmt.Println(dag[value])
}
```

Working code on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ngRT9wnRocr)

Answer (score 0):

you can enumerate the array and transfer the number and the string

```
func GetNextDay(someday string){
    for i, v := range dag{
      if v == someday {
          if i==6 {
              i = 0
          }else {
             i = i + 1
          }
          return dag[i]
      }
    }
    return "no such day in a week"
}
```